# etc directory in UNIX

Tags: unix

Please explain the usage of /etc directory and UNIX? Can we have comman setting defined for all users in this directory?

Comment: This question is not programming related. I.e. , you aren't asking how to progrmatically read or manipulate configurations in /etc. This question would be better answered on superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

Here's the "official" answer:
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCHOSTSPECIFICSYSTEMCONFIGURATION

It's similar to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE hive of the Windows registry: It contains system-wide settings for software (as opposed to per-user settings).

Answer (score 1):

Please read this:
http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCHOSTSPECIFICSYSTEMCONFIGURATION

Answer (score 1):

Please find the links given below:

[File System](http://docs.openafs.org/AdminGuide/ch11s04.html)

[Article on /etc](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8601)

Answer (score 0):

Generally only root/wheel write access into /etc/  Common settings application wide, possible, but I still prefer applications to store their configurations in their own filesystem structure.  We needn't muddy the filesystem by going about shoving non-system application configs in there, let us *not* repeat the registry ills.